# Excel help formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help on a formula.

I have set up a worksheet with 24 tabs. 12 review sheets, one for each month. 12 sheets for the P&L each month.

I want to copy and paste the p and l into the relevant month and have the data extract into the review sheet.

On the p and l, there are various cost centres. In the cost centres there are various spend categories. Some of the spend categories repeat so I need a formula that ensures it pulls the data from the correct cost centre AND spend category. I used a v look up with an if error but it hits a wall when the spend categories repeat. In the image, you will see that Uniforms and Footwear as an example appears in two cost centres, so V Look up only finds the first one. I need it to find the value that matches both the spend category and the cost centre.

Please help

Thank you

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the exact problem you are facing? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: I have tried =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B141,'JAN P&L'!$A$19:$B$360,2,FALSE),"")

Comment: this basically searches works except when a spend category is present in two different cost centres, it picks up the first answer again

Comment: When  you say _p and l_  is that an I or an L?  As in columns P and I or the sheet P&L?

Comment: I would separate your cost center and spend category into 2 different columns in all sheets. Then you can use a SUMIFS formula.

Comment: P and L is profit and Loss which is what I am reviewing so the tab is P&L

Comment: Thank you, I have done something similar at the moment, thank you for the advice